# HIghstock Timeseries data date format

Tags: time-series, highcharts

I want to create a timeseries chart in Highstock. the data that i receive from the web service is of the following format.
For date: "2015/06/28"
For week: "week 28 2015"
For month: "Jun 2015"
For year: "2015"

How should I convert the data in the series?

Currently I am processing the data in this way:

```
var date = "2015/07/28";
text = date.split('/');
date = new Date(text[0], parseInt(text[1], 10) - 1, text[2]);
newdate = date.getTime();
```

I am pushing the newdate in the series.

But due to this my chart is shrinked. There is lot of space left in the left and right of the chart.

[image: shrinked chart]

Answer (score 1):

You can edit that by [dateTimeLabelFormats](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats)

```
dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
    second: '%H:%M:%S',
    minute: '%H:%M',
    hour: '%H:%M',
    day: '%e. %b',
    week: '%e. %b',
    month: '%b \'%y',
    year: '%Y'
}
```

Comment: I have added this code in the chart code. But it doesn't effect the chart. Still i have the same issue.

Comment: how to pass the date in the series.?

Comment: You need to have a pairs [x,y] where x is timestamp, time in milisecond.